# Jquery Select Equivalent in Knockout Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and having tough time trying to resolve this.

I am trying to accomplish this Select functionality in Knockout. When I select the text, I want to highlight the border.

https://api.jquery.com/select/

Right now, in Knockout, I am able to highlight the border using click but when user selects the text directly in the textbox, Am unable to highlight the border.

Here is the html for that. There is lot going on in that textbox. If my question is not clear, Please ask so that I can explain better.

```html
<input class="name" type="text"
data-bind="click: function (y, event) { $root.SelectedWay($parent.Way); $root.SelectChild(y, event); $(event.target).select(); },
typeahead: { 'source': $root.All(), 'sorter': $root.ColorSorter, 'updater': $root.UpdateSelectedColor, 'highlighter': $root.HighlightColor, 'matcher': $root.MatchColor },
css: { 'selected': Selected }, 
value: Name" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about a custom binding. here is one where the border turns red using the jquery select

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.jquerySelect = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    $(element).select(function() {
      $(this).css("border", "5px solid red");
    });
    $(element).val(valueAccessor()());
  },
  //update the control when the view model changes
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    $(element).val(valueAccessor()());
  }
};



function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.myObservable = ko.observable('hello world');
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-bind="jquerySelect: myObservable" />
```

Comment: Hi, You can already see the input data-bind in my code. How can I add this functionality to the existing data-bind

Comment: think you just need to change value: name to  jquerySelect: name.  the custom binding will replace your value binding

Comment: hi, I think I need to call this $root.SelectChild(y, event) in the code above I mentioned. How can I call this in place of changing the border to red. The selectchild function which I mentioned already have the code which I need to do.

Comment: why don't you try make a runnable reproducable code snippet similiar to what I've done. guessing at your requirements is probably not going to work well for anyone.

Comment: Hey, I think making that will take long time, code is very big, approximately 3000 lines, but I will try, As I said, I am new to knockout, still trying to figure out on how to do it